# PC BIOS doesn't boot after failed reset to defaults

Tags: boot, bios, motherboard, cmos, dram

Good day.
I have bought brand new PC details and did a setup.
Firstly everything went fine, but I had some issues with installing W11, so I went to bios options, changed few things there, after reboot there was only my motherboard logo showing up, I thought something's going wrong and forced a reboot again (now I guess that I have interrupted the bios reset to factory settings).

After this my PC launches, but there is no signal, no working USB etc.

1. I tried to clear CMOS by touching 2 pins with the screwdriver while the PSU off,
2. tried holding the turn on button for 10-15 seconds both alone and with the reset button,
3. tried taking the battery out for 15 minutes
4. tried replacing the RAM to other slots

What I still haven't tried is shorting the 1st and 8th pin of M_BIOS chip.

After the night I turned the PC on and saw the connected keyboard working (but no signal, because there was no graphics card connected at this moment). So I turned the PC off, inserted the graphics card and tried again, but came back to my problem. After that the same without the graphics card and after checking all pins connected.

It seems that after long period of time the bios has boot one from the backup and continued to boot from main after that one time.

What could possibly help? Have I bricked my motherboard?

Configuration:

Motherboard: Gigabyte AM4 Aorus B450M
CPU: Ryzen 3600
RAM: Patriot Viper Steel 2x8GB PC25600 3200MHz
SSD: M.2 Kingston NV1 250GB
Graphics card: Radeon RX580
PSU: Proton BDF-500S 500W

Comment: It seems that after long period of time the bios has boot one from the backup and continued to boot from main after that one time.   ....  If the computer is now working, what you describe is BIOS Recovery. I have that feature on my new Lenovo Laptop.